# Change JSON data from API endpoint for rendering in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a React App, and I have a component for a tabular data.
I am calling an API endpoint that gives a response like this:

```
{
 "bitcoin": {
 "usd": 48904,
 "usd_market_cap": 925245685071.0829,
 "usd_24h_vol": 21781197864.07206,
 "usd_24h_change": -0.4811309022054875,
 "last_updated_at": 1640267722
 }
}
```

The way I structured my components are it accepts "bitcoin" as one of the arguments for the API endpoint, and rendering the data in my child component is like this:

```
         <TableCell>{data.bitcoin.usd_market_cap}</TableCell>
         <TableCell>{data.bitcoin.usd_24h_vol}</TableCell>
         <TableCell>{data.bitcoin.usd_24h_change}</TableCell>
```

How can I change the bitcoin part in my rendering code so that it can accept the prop that I added to the component like this:

```
<CoinTableRow coin="bitcoin" currency="usd" />
```

so that I can just use do:

```
<CoinTableRow coin="ethereum" currency="usd" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object can have its properties accessed in one of two ways: either by using the dot syntax you're using now, e.g. `data.bitcoin`, or by using array access syntax, e.g. `data["bitcoin"]`.

So simply replace all instances of `data.bitcoin` with `data[props.coin]`:

```
<TableCell>{data[props.coin].usd_market_cap}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{data[props.coin].usd_24h_vol}</TableCell>
<TableCell>{data[props.coin].usd_24h_change}</TableCell>
```